# Microsoft Access rtf to html conversion

Tags: html, rtf

Does anyone know of a rtf to html convertor routine that works in Access? 2007 but migrating to 2019. I have tried the one here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/141fb4cb-5dd8-4b01-bd83-8146a05cf54f/convert-rtf-format-to-html-format

I can get it to execute without errors but it doesn’t produce any results.  It refers to a Microsoft Web Browser ActiveX library that doesn’t seem to exist.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you invoke Word to do the translation?  What I mean is, if you've got a machine with Access installed, can you be reasonably certain that Word will also be available?  There seem to be plenty of references where people just use (background) Word automation to achieve what you're after - and it is a pretty standard Word capability

Comment: Craig, of course I have considered that.  The link that I included with my question has a comment that the html code generated by that method is unnecessarily lengthy.  It does seem to be possible to do this using clipboard but the article is pretty old.  I actually suspect that the IE which comes with Windows 10 may have lost some of the capabilities of earlier versions as Edge (subscription required) is Microsoft’s favored browser.

Comment: Yeah, I found some stuff about there being "Edge" add-ins for Office apps, but I'm not sure that they're going to be ActiveX controls that can be invoked within VBA code .... you know how all things browser are these days, everything is tight, tight, tight security.  That's the main reason I figured Word is probably you're simplest option .... but, of course, you have to be sure that Word will be available on the PC.  Otherwise cross your fingers for an answer from someone who's done what you're asking about recently